# Python replace unicode characters with spaces of the same length in utf-8

Tags: python, unicode

I have some text like

```
Print\n* Share\n\n\nNUMBER:\u00a00958\n\nPOLICY\n\n1. CRITERIA FOR INITIAL APPROVAL\n\n\n\n    Aetna considers\u00a0gemcitabine (Gemzar)
```

This is causing issues when importing to a data labelling tool, as the labels are offset by the length of the unicode character in utf-8.

For example, /u00a0 is a two character symbol in utf-8: `0xC2 0xA0 (c2a0)`

In the example above, I have a label at `gemcitabine`, but it shows up labelled in the labelling tool as `mcitabine (`, because there are two `/u00a0` characters before it.

If I replace both `/u00a0` characters with two spaces   , the labels show up correctly.

I was just wondering, how could I detect and replace unicode symbols that represent more than one character in utf-8 with the same number of spaces?

Comment: Wouldn't `x = x.replace('\u00a0',' ')` do it?  Or perhaps you should encode using some encoding other than UTF-8.

Comment: The length of the UTF-8 sequence is not a good predictor for the on-screen width of a character. (Unfortunately, the on-screen width of the glyph used to display the Unicode character is not predictable from the code point, either.)

Comment: @TimRoberts I've indeed tried what you suggested, and it works, but I'd like to replace all instances of multi-character symbols with the same number of spaces, not just \u00a0.

Comment: Then don't convert to UTF-8, convert to ANSI and ignore exceptions.

Comment: `\u00a0` is ` ` (U+00A0,  *No-Break Space*)…

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it like this:

```
        convert_to_utf8 = lambda char : char if len(char.encode('utf-8')) <= 1 else ''.ljust(len(char.encode('utf-8')))
        string_array = [convert_to_utf8(char) for char in obj['data']]
        obj['data'] = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in string_array])
```

where obj['data'] is the string that contains multi-character symbols.